# How to capture negative response from user in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am using `input-view` for selection and i can see none button at the bottom of the screen.I haven't included any `conversation-driver` yet i can see the button. How to avoid that? Event if we can not avoid it, how can i add the event-listener on this? If user click or say none, I want to give user a custom message and pass it to other intent. is it possible?

Also is it possible to give user other option if none of the utterances matched with the defined one? for example

User: what is the temperature of Oakland?
bixby: today, it is 73 F in san francisco.
User: I want to buy land on mars?

These kind of question is out of context. how to handle it?
Now in this case i want user to be prompt like "It is not possible for me to get the information, but I can tell you weather forecast of your current location. Would you like to know?" User might say yes or no. Yes would redirect it to the weather intent and no will say thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A "None" `conversation-driver` is shown when the `input-view` is for a Concept that is optional (`min(Optional)`) for your Action. Changing it to `min(Required)` will remove the "None" `conversation-driver`.

If you want to keep the concept Optional as an input for the Action, you can add a `default-init` ([link to relevant docs](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input.default-init)) to your Action to kick off another Action that would help the user provide you a correct input.

Bixby cannot create a path for out-of-scope utterances. The idea is that, since every user's personal Bixby will contain a number of capsules, your capsule will get called only if a user's utterance matches the types of utterances you have trained Bixby to recognize via your training file.

Comment: Fine.. I will add `min(required)` to remove the none button but what if user said `none`, then how would you handle that. I have created an intent named `LetItFallBack` and I check in my action file that if the valid input is not provided by user then I replan the intent to `LetItFallBack`, where I simply give user msg that we are sorry and we can't process this request. Would you like something else and based the response I suggest user something. But now I am getting error on simulator that `Unable to attach plan from 1.0.1-myAppID.api.GetRecepie#1.0.1-myAppID.api.RecepieResultreplan intent`

Comment: If the user says `none` for an `input-view` that requires an answer, Bixby will not move forward and ask the user to provide the input again so it will never move past a required input unless it gets it. The `LetItFallBack` Action you suggested would never be called.